# With a read only realm, am I required to make a referance to the path for every time I use it?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a preoloaded read-only realm-db that is placed in the main bundle.

Am I required to make a referance to that path for every query I make or is there an easier way to do this?

```
//Locate database
    let localRealmPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dogs", ofType: "realm")!

    let realm = RLMRealm(path: localRealmPath, readOnly: true, error: nil)

    let dog = Dog.objectsInRealm(realm, "name = 'Pat'").firstObject() as Dog
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey fisher yes you do have to refer to it each time, so you have the proper realm. Can you share some ideas on what you feel would be your ideal way to use a realm?

Comment: Thanks for the info! It would be awesome to have a tag feature. Let's say you can reference the realm with name or tag. So you could pick it up with let's say "RLMRealm.realmWithTag("Dogs")". But it's probably hard to accomplish when the path is not known.

Comment: I see that would be tricky since we need to find a way to set the correct path related to that tag as you mentioned. 

As Marius mentioned below, as long as you aren't accessing the realm from different threads you can store them in your properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate / retrieve a new `RLMRealm` instance for every query, you make. You can reuse the read-only Realm for any number of arbitrary read operations. Just make sure that you don't access the `RLMRealm` instance from different threads.

Comment: Thanks! I've made a lazy var of the realm that works fine and can be reused inside the scope of the ViewController. But i'll have to to that in every VC where I need to make a fetch. But it's no biggie, just wanted to check if there was an easier option:)!